# A better way for a smoothly transition between highly and low detailed textures

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, transparency

I have the highly and low detailed pictures:

[image]
[image]

And I would like to make a smoothly transition between them, for exapmle, on the one side. I put them on top of each other (as laeyrs), make "Match Color", set "Fade", then add a layer mask and use "Gradient tool" for edge transparency. But nevertheless the result is not very good, especially when zooming in (last image). So, maybe there is a way to improve this (Even using programs other than Photoshop if necessary.)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe not an easy question, but what exactly is “not good” about your attempt? Or why not just use the high detail picture?

Comment: I'm trying to make some highly detailed surface area among  global Earth surface texture for a flight simulator, and the main purpose is the colour matching and making a smoothly transition between high and low textures as best as possible. I don't like transparency in my attempt. Maybe there're better ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, your process is correct.

What you could try is, taking your high-resolution image, resampling it to, let's say half resolution, and making an intermediate step. Fade it the same way you did.

---

Complementing using the lens blur. https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/adjusting-image-sharpness-blur.html

The lens blur can make an increasing blur. You can make a selection or prepare a gradient to determine the zones that will recieve the blur. Apply it to a high-resolution image and stop when the look is similar to the low-resolution image.

Apply the low-resolution image as you already did.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. What I don't like in my attempt is transparency. I think about some blur with variable pixelization (if it's possible to do).

Comment: Photoshop has a feature “lens blur” by which a soft mask can control the blur radius.

Comment: Another idea is to use map features (eg roads or edges of fields) to transition from one source to another.

Comment: @KrisVanBael, thanks, the first idea can be useful.

Comment: @Rafael, thanks, I'd like to try this. Should I use the lens blur after my result with the gradient operation or instead of it? And sorry, what do you mean in "apply the low-resolution image"?